# CSS General Sibling Selector vs Header

Tags: css, css-selectors

This is a basic but tricky question about styling header with General Sibling Selector. Many people make a mistake about using it (and write books!). It seems for me useless:

```
<h1>Title 1</h1>
<p>text</p><p>text</p>
<h2>Title 1.1</h2>
<p>text</p><p>text</p>
<h3>Title 1.1.1</h3>
<p>text</p><p>text</p>
<h2>Title 1.2</h2>
<p>text</p><p>text</p>
<h3>Title 1.2.1</h3>
<p>text</p><p>text</p>
```

I would like to style all my P with a margin:

```
H1 ~ P { margin-left: 1em; }
H2 ~ P { margin-left: 2em; }
H3 ~ P { margin-left: 3em; }
```

It simply can't work !

Because P of section 1.2 are after a H3 and styled by H3 isntead of H2.

- I can't use H2+P because I can have many P.
- I don't want to use `<div>` around the P it's too cludge.
- if I do not put a wraper on this code all P in the page after this code will be selected !

Is there a way to scope Tilde ? Or handle this issue smartly?

Comment: Your HTML sample is invalid. Check your closing header tags.

Comment: Please check your markup once again. They are not closed properly.

Comment: till now, you haven't accepted answers on any of you old questions - this doesn't look very good and wo't motivate peaple to help if if they know they won't get rewarded for that. (if you don't kno: you can accept an answer by klicking on the tick-mark next to it, you should dothis on the answer that helped you the most on your way to solve your problem)

Comment: @oezi Well in my previous question answers was incorrect so I will not gives a good answer for them.

Comment: @Jason McCreary and @Chinmayee why does my markup is invalid ? I check on HTML validator, <p> and <h> seems to be closed properly ?

Comment: Sorry looking at answers I didn't see @Gumbo have edited my wrong HTML. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn the css the other way around (the last definition wins, so i think this works (but i havn't tested))

new CSS:

```
h3 ~ p { margin-left: 3em; }
h2 ~ p { margin-left: 2em; }
h1 ~ p { margin-left: 1em; }
```

Comment: The order Jean-Phillippe Encausse had originally would override correctly if the headings were simply sequential, but in his (more realistic) markup the headings switch back and forth from `h3` to `h2`.

Comment: Well about CSS typo I like to Uppercase Tags because it is a very good way to improve readability: Tag uppercase, Class camelcase or lowercase (PRE.first {} or A.link IMG.icon {}).

Comment: About answer, basically the html can have many h1-6 tags, so it could be <h1><h2><h3><h1><h2><h3>...<P>. At last, P is next to a h1 and a h2 and a h3. 

So, any way you change order of CSS declaration it can't work because the last declaration will win. It seems, the only way to make it work would be if a declaration of h1-6 override an over declaration of h1-6.